# Is it better to install VMWare WS on Windows 7 or Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, vmware-workstation

I'd like to run both operating systems, but wondering which is better as the root host.  So I could load VMWare Workstation on Windows 7 then load Windows 8 as a virtual machine, or visa versa.  Not sure if there's any opinions on this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it really matters which one is the host OS and which one is the guest OS.  They will both run fine as host or guest.  For the host operating system I would use the one that I am more comfortable with and/or use more often.  That way you will not have to use the guest OS as often.

As you probably know running a guest OS does consume more resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Windows 8 as the host and Windows 7 as the virtual machine because at this point support for a Windows 7 in a VM is going to be better than a Windows 8 VM considering all the new UI in Windows 8. You should have far less trouble with Windows 8 as the host than you would running it as the VM.

Answer (score -1):

I would use Windows 7 as the host system because the VMWare Workstation client for Windows 7 is obviously longer in develeopment and recieved a lot more bug fixes and OS related improvements so far then the version for Windows 8.
The same goes for the the guest of course but the driver model of Windows 8 hasn't really changed and the VMware drivers should work just fine on a Windows 8 guest.

Thats just a logical view on it, to find out if VMWare Workstation produces any problems when running on a Winodws 8 host you will have to try it out as stability problems can be very system specific and differ from machine to machine.